# Deleting table rows using Table ID

Tags: javascript

I am using

```
"$$('tbody')[0].parentNode.removeChild($$('tbody')[0]);
```

to delete all the rows of a table except the table header.

There are two tables in UI page. Every time its deleting the rows of first table. Where can I put table id to refer the table whose rows needs to be deleted?

Comment: What does `$$` refer to? jQuery?

Comment: It looks like you're using prototype.js, you should add a tag for that.

Comment: If you're using *prototype.js*, the [*$$* function](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar-dollar/) takes a CSS selector, so you'd need `$$('#tableId tbody')` to get the tbodies of the table with ID *tableId*.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an ID on your `<table>`, then you can just use an id selector to access it i.e. `$("#myId")`. Use this with the descendant selector i.e. `$("#myId tbody")` will access the body of your target table.

Also, if you are already using a framework like jQuery you can just use the `empty()` function to clear out the children. No need to go up and down the parent/child node chain.

HTML

```
<table id="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Delete Me</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JS

```
$("#myTable tbody").empty()
```

Comment: I tried this way but it didn't work. I am passing table Id as argument to a function. It returned an error "cant take value of null" . Thanks

Comment: @ShrutikaAgrawal—please clarify if you are using prototype.js or not. The prototype.js *$* function takes an ID and, if not found, returns *null*, which fits with your issues and your OP. Until you clarify the library you're using, no one can help you further.

Comment: I am using this code in client scripting of service now platform, here i need not to import any library. All the JavaScript, Jquery and angular Js code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

$('tbody') will grab all tbody elements in the page

If you are using jQuery target the parent element or give the tbody an ID instead

```
$('#tableid tbody').empty();
$('#tbodyid').empty();
```

To remove the [tbody] element as well, just use remove instead of empty

```
$('#tableid').children('tbody').remove();
```

Comment: I am getting the error "uUncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of null" when used $('#tableid').children('tbody').remove();
Please help!

Comment: Also , getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'empty' of null" when used $('#tbodyid').empty();

Comment: are you using jQuery or what is your $$ framework referenced above?